# Toggle nested array value in update pipeline with $cond

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to toggle names of people who liked a comment in the comments array in a document.

Better visualized than words: [Mongo Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GHHaKAFnKDH)

---

**Explanation**:

Suppose I have a document

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "comments": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Comment 1",
        "likedBy": [
          "Tomato",
          "Potato"
        ],
        
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "Comment 2",
        "likedBy": [
          "Carrot"
        ],
        
      },
      
    ],
    
  },
```

I would like to "toggle" a `likedBy` value "Potato" on a particular comment, matched by `comments.id` in a document.

---

So far, I came up with this

```
db.collection.update({
  id: 1,
  "comments.id": 1,
  
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "comments.likedBy": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [
              "Potato",
              "$comments.likedBy"
            ]
          },
          {
            $setDifference: [
              "$comments.likedBy",
              [
                "Potato"
              ]
            ]
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$comments.likedBy",
              [
                "Potato"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ],
        
      },
      
    },
    
  }
])
```

---

Expected output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "comments": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "likedBy": [
           "Tomato",
           //!! Potato is removed from here
        ],
        "text": "Comment 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "likedBy": [
          "Carrot"
        ],
        "text": "Comment 2"
      }
    ],

  }
```

However, I am getting incorrect result. I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong with the positional operators.

Comment: you want on  id=1, comment.id=1, on likedBy to add the "Potato" if missing, or remove the "Potato" if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- this removes the `"Potato"` from `likeBy` if it exists else adds the `"Potato"`
- `$map` on comments, if `comment.id=1` add/remove the `"Potato"` else leave comment as it is
- in the bellow code `$$this` is the comment sub-document

*Not sure if this is what you need exactly but produces the result you want, and looks like your query.

*about the paths, "$comments.likedBy" is an array that contains all the `likedBy` arrays from all comments, with `$map` bellow `$$this.likedBy` is used to contain only the likedBy of a specific comment, i think this was the problem.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70173686-m)

```js
update(
{"id": 1,"comments.id": 1},
[{"$set": 
    {"comments": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": "$comments",
          "in": 
          {"$cond": 
            [{"$eq": ["$$this.id", 1]},
              {"$mergeObjects": 
                ["$$this",
                  {"likedBy": 
                    {"$cond": 
                      [{"$in": ["Potato", "$$this.likedBy"]},
                       {"$setDifference": ["$$this.likedBy", ["Potato"]]},
                       {"$concatArrays": ["$$this.likedBy", ["Potato"]]}]}}]},
              "$$this"]}}}}}])
```

Comment: In this case, since the pipeline is already checking `{"$eq": ["$$this.id", 1]}`, is it safe to remove the `"comments.id": 1` from the find query?

Comment: its not just safe its better also, the only reason to keep it is if you have too many id=1 (i mean the root id) and also have an index on  `comment.id`. i don't think you need it but i kept it because i didn't know how is your data. The query never change a comment if doesn't have `comment.id=1` so its safe

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Works wonderfully.